# Accessing the iPhone SMS file

Tags: iphone, ios

I  try to access sms db file in xcode but fail.
I know its path that is "/private/var/mobile/Library/SMS/sms.db"
When i try to access. the file read no permission error occur.

Is any way to access sms db file or change its permission in xcode. Thanks in advance.
The code which i try on iphone jailbroken is

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSString *path = @"/var/mobile/Library/SMS/sms.db";
NSError *error;
NSArray *content = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:&error];
NSLog(@"%@", error);
NSLog(@"Content: %@", content);
if ([fileManager isReadableFileAtPath:path]) {
    NSLog(@"");
    NSLog(@"ReadAble");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"Not readable");
}
if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:path])
    NSLog(@"File Exist");
else
NSLog(@"No");
```

further when i try to call_history.db file . it is accessible. but sms.db not.

Comment: *Luckily* Apple prevents you from accessing private data like the SMS DB. I don't want apps snooping on my private data like you want to do.

Comment: But it could be useful for a personal app :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is currently no way to do so on stock iOS. It is restricted by the framework itself, and thus not possible as it is.

On a jailbroken iPhone this is possible, but it will perhaps only work on the same jailbreak of the very same version.

EDIT:
One other solution, which won't pass to AppStore, is to find some exploitable bug in the iOS (there must be a lot, check out how jailbreaks are done) to gain root access in your app. Then you would be able to access the data you want on a non-jailbroken iPhone. But it will probably only work on the version on which you developed it.

Comment: Good answer.  If you want this app to be sold on the app store, don't do stuff that will make Apple unhappy with your app.

Comment: Can you give me some idea how it is possible on jailbroken iphone .. ??

Comment: On a jailbroken iPhone you can have root access, thus read access to the file you want. You can for example expose a method which permit to run a code as root, or even as kernel. (It is much more related to kernel hacking than to iOS programming, with an exception if you use a existing jailbreak which expose the right method).

Comment: I can Access my call_history.db file by method as describe above. just changing the path to "/var/wireless/Library/CallHistory/call_history.db".. But not sms.db file. kindly describe the difference of both file. Thanks

Comment: I don't know the whole details and I have never searched anything about iOS hacking so I can't say much more. Check out the file permissions ! Or gain root access, again :)

Comment: You're welcome. Checkout reverse-engineering and existing jailbreaks source and I'm sure you could do this.

Answer (score 2):

Every iOS application runs inside a sandbox. There's no way to access files outside the sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,you just need to deploy the app in /Application folder currently you app would be deploying in /var/mobile/Application folder the application iside it does not have the permission to access /private/var/mobile/Library/SMS/sms.db you can use Theos or IOSopendev to make the whole process easy.