# Manipulate iOS SMS Database

Tags: iphone, ios, sms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Accessing the iPhone SMS file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8501941/accessing-the-iphone-sms-file)

On the iOS platform, is it possible to manipulate the core SMS database.

For example, let's pretend I wanted to create an SMS App, this app would basically be reading off of the database of the SMS app on the iOS platform. If anyone sends me a text, it goes to the default app and then to mine as well. if I deleted a specific message from my app, would remove it from the default app as well?

I know I can do this with Android, as GoSMS has certainly proved this is one shot, but iOS seems a bit more stringent, so wondering if any of this is possible in the first place.

And if it is possible, are there any tutorials, guides, etc on doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not possible, nor will it ever be. It's private to the user. No one is allowed to tamper, read, manipulate this. There is absolutely no reason to.

You cannot create an SMS app.

Don't mistake SMS app with IM app, such as WhatsApp.

Comment: Oh im well aware of the difference between IM and SMS, and knew a great deal of IM applications on the App Store, but I havent had an iOS device since my iPod Touch 2nd Generation and thought maybe things might have changed since that time :p Thanks for the quick response tho!

Comment: No problemo, it's really about protecting the user and I totally agree with that. Android in my opinion for this kind of thing is ridiculously open, there's a lot of crap-ware out there and I'd absolutely go crazy if I was ticked into installing an app that could wipe my sms's