# Is there a way to display a screen from another app within your own?

Tags: ios, ios6

I've recently looked into accessing sms messages and found that it is not possible to get them without jailbreaking.

[background info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8501941/accessing-the-iphone-sms-file)

A possible workaround is to access the sms app, and display a portion of it within my own. Is such a method possible? If so how would I go about doing that?

Comment: The security implications of allowing this would be enormous. There's a reason the SMS database is locked - privacy. If your app could see the contents of the Messages app, it could use OCR to see your personal messages, and this is not OK. Not to mention viewing my bank balance in Safari, password reset links in Mail, my Facebook Code Generator details, etc.

Comment: Yeah, general Apple rule - app A cannot access app B data, end of story.